# Concat multiple rows with a delimiter in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, concatenation

I need to concat string values row wise with '~' as delimiter.
I have the following data:

[image]

I need to concat 'Comment' column for each 'id' in the ascending order of 'row_id' with '~' as delimiter.

Expected output is as below:

[image]

`GROUP_CONCAT` is not an option since its not recognized in my Hive version.
I can use `collect_set` or `collect_list`, but I won't be able to insert delimiter in between.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please replace the images with text.

Comment: Did you tried to use the concat functions provided by Hive ?
Check out this link :- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Yes i tried all the concat functions given. all of them are for column wise operations. I am looking for row wise operation

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**collect_list** returns array, not string.
Array can be converted to delimited string using **concat_ws**.

---

This will work, with no specific order of comments.

```
select      id
           ,concat_ws('~',collect_list(comment)) as comments

from        mytable 

group by    id
;
```

---

```
+----+-------------+
| id |  comments   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ABC~PRQ~XYZ |
|  2 | LMN~OPQ     |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: can we use `concat() over partition by ()` clause to get the same result ?